# System Slow After Uprading Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, updates, performance

i have an ubuntu network machine which has release of 10.04.1 LTS Lucid. on this system i have apache, postgresql and django. for some app. development i have to install php and php-curl... due to being on network, i have exported wmvare machine to internet and firstly i have upgraded system and then install php5 packages on it.

After all replacing it with its old place, i have considered that the new system query is some slow according to another.

Old system query time : `140 ms`

New system query time : `9.11 s`

i have checked `/etc/network interface` and it seems there is no problem.
i have checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and it seems ok 
i have checked `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and only host section is different from old one which old system has `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

and then i have checked `time host -t A services.myapp.com` and i got

```
real 0m0.355s
user 0m0.010s
sys  0m0.020s
```

and i have checked apache2 HostnameLookups :

```
find /etc/apache2/ -type f | xargs grep -i HostnameLookups
```

it returned :

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:HostnameLookups Off
```

and now what can i have to check for boosting my system as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method: Control and Conquer.

Stop one process and see its impact on the given time. If no change, continue so long that such a change come.

I would start with Django, then with Apache and then with PHP.

So first find out what may cause the problem.

It is apparent that some of your code is in old standards and after upgrading some language, probably PHP or Python, the things changed.

I would like to see what process take most memory in your system.
So what process is causing the 9.11s delay?